# How to turn down interview for position I don't want?

Tags: interviewing, communication, hiring-process

I've received an invitation to interview for an internship position. However, I'm looking for a full time position and want to turn the invitation down politely, since I'd rather not burn bridges with companies in my field. How do I politely tell the contact that I appreciate the offer, but will pass for this reason? Should I give a reason?

Comment: This is not breaking up with a girlfriend, it's 1 million times simpler. Just... don't overthink it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Politely tell the contact that you appreciate the offer, but will pass because you are looking for a full time job.

Nothing more need be said.